# Given a triangle $ABC$ and its incenter I. If $P,Q$ are points on BI and CI so that $2PAQ=BAC$. Prove that $PDQ=90$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

Given a triangle $ABC$ and its incenter I. If $P,Q$ are points on $BI$ and $CI$ so that $2\angle PAQ=\angle BAC$. If $D$ is the point where the inscribed circle of $ABC$ intersects $BC$, prove that $\angle PDQ=90$.

[image]

If $X\in BI$ we state $f(X)$ is the only point on $CI$ which is collinear with $A$ and is the points which becomes of X if we rotate $X$ around $A$ by angle $\frac{1}{2}\angle ABC$. Hence $f(P)=Q$.  We also have that $f(B)=I$ and $f(I)=C$. Also if $I_1$ and $I_2$ the incenter of $\triangle ABD, \triangle ACD$ respectively then $f(I_1)=f(I_2)$

This is as far as I got. I believe it should be able to finish like this, but I've gotten stuck. Could you please help me finish it off?

Comment: I don't think that image is alright. Is it?

Comment: You are right, one minute I'll correct it

Comment: @lee I have corrected it, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: I think that the better way to phrase your approach would be to let $f(X) = \text{ angle between $X$ and its rotation by $\alpha/2$}$ and then somehow argue that this is a linear function, which then gives you your desired answer. But I don't see how this would be trivial to argue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To continue your idea: the map $f$ is a projective map from the set of points on $BI$ to the set of points on $CI$. We can consider another map $g$ that sends $X\in BI$ to the point $Y\in CI$ such that $\angle XDY=90^{\circ}$. This map $g$ is also projective, so to show that $f\equiv g$, it suffices to check that they are equal at three points.

But this is easy: $f(B)=I=g(B)$, $f(I)=C=g(I)$ and $f(I_1)=I_2=g(I_1)$.

---

An alternative approach: $\angle DIQ+\angle AIB=180^{\circ}$, so $I$ has an isogonal conjugate wrt quadrilateral $ABDQ$. But it's easy to see that the isogonal conjugate must in fact be $P$.

So $\angle PDQ=\angle IDB=90^{\circ}$.

Comment: What is isogonal conjugate with respect to quadrilateral?

Comment: @Aqua To construct the isogonal conjugate of $P$ wrt $ABCD$, just reflect lines $AP$, $BP$, $CP$, $DP$ in the angle bisectors of $\angle A$, $\angle B$, $\angle C$, $\angle D$ respectively. In general, these lines won't concur, but they will when $\angle APB+\angle CPD=180^{\circ}$.

Comment: You can prove this with trig. Ceva also?

Comment: @Aqua maybe. I think the standard proof is to project $P$ onto the sides, then both conditions are equivalent to the four projections being concyclic.